# What to use instead of ArrayList to group data?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have to eventually show the K-menas clusters (centers of clusters and dots belonging to cluster). Now I have centers and dataset both ArrayList and then I join ArrayLists in clusters (also ArrayList). But here i don't know how to add color to each cluster. This means every iteration colors of center will stay the same, but points will change color depending on witch  cluster they belong (= witch center is the closest).

Should I use hashmap? Key is color? How to change?

```
/*  n= Number of centers, int lowerBound = 0, int upperBound =1000000 */

    public static List<PointXY> randomCentri(int n, int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
      List<PointXY> centers = new ArrayList<>(n);
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          float x = (float)(Math.random() * (upperBound - lowerBound) + lowerBound);
          float y = (float)(Math.random() * (upperBound - lowerBound) + lowerBound);
          PointXY point = new PointXY(x, y);
          centers.add(point);
      }
      return centers;
  }

// Dataset from file (.txt) (GPS coordinates)

    public static List<PointXY> podatki(String inputFile) throws Exception {
      List<PointXY> dataset = new ArrayList<>();
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
      String line;

      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          String[] tokens = line.split(",");
          float x = Float.valueOf(tokens[0]);
          float y = Float.valueOf(tokens[1]);
          PointXY point = new PointXY(x, y);

              dataset.add(point);
      }
      br.close();
      return dataset;
  }
```

Basically this is core of the K-Means algorithm. We first assign a list of lists called clusters, which is initialized with centers.size() empty lists. Then, for each data in our dataset, we get the nearest center index through the method getNearestPointIndex previously defined and append the data to the cluster list of the nearest center. The third loop, for each cluster in clusters, we calculate the mean and append it to the noviCentri variable, which is used as the return of our method.

```
public static List<PointXY> noviCentri(List<PointXY> dataset, List<PointXY> centers) {
  List<List<PointXY>> clusters = new ArrayList<>(centers.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < centers.size(); i++) {
      clusters.add(new ArrayList<PointXY>());
  }
  for (PointXY data : dataset) {
      int index = data.najblizjaTIndex(centers);
      clusters.get(index).add(data);
  }
  List<PointXY> noviCentri = new ArrayList<>(centers.size());
  for (List<PointXY> cluster : clusters) {
      noviCentri.add(PointXY.povprecje(cluster));
  }
  return noviCentri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Define a "DataSet" class. One member of the DataSet class will now be your list of points. Another member will be the colour.
- Or... have both a "DataSet" class and a "ClusterCentre" class. The ClusterCentre class has a colour member (as well as the actual centre point); DataSet has a 'clusterCentre' member that points to the relevant ClusterCentre instance once determined
- Or... you *could* indeed map a List to a Colour and not define any other classes. If you do this, use an IdentityHashMap in your particular case: this is a special implementation of Map that maps a specific key object instance (a list in your case) to the value object (colour in your case) in question. [Later on in time, learn about the hashCode() and equals() methods, about how these are implemented in the standard ArrayList class, and therefore why a standard HashMap would be a bad idea for your particular case...]

So as you can see, you have a choice of implementation. Which is "correct"? Well, as always it depends on your requirements: is the colour mapping a one-off, "throwaway" use where you just temporarily attribute the colours to the lists? In that case, using the Map option could be a simple, sufficient solution. Or do you see it more as a "fundamental" attribute of the data sets that needs to be permanently attributed to them and passed from method to method... Will you need DataSet and ClusterCentre classes anyway, to add other attributes, in which case you may as well start creating this "proper" data structure from the outset and make it easier to extend later on when you need to...

Answer (score 0):

The cluster's color is a property of the cluster, not the data points. You are always going to need *k* colors for the *k* means. So, right at the start, assign one color to each cluster as:

> var color = new String[] {c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, c<sub>3</sub>, c<sub>k</sub>};

---

Now, continue with your k means clustering and when the iterations are finished, simply extract the color of each data point through its cluster by:

> var pointColor = color[clusterIndex];

Comment: Thanks for answer but I have sub question and couldn't ask here because char limitation so I made new question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57737914/in-what-way-assign-one-arraylist-value-to-another-arraylist-of-different-type